# Issue in grunt build

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am getting the issue below when I run grunt build all of sudden. 
**Warning: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-resource failed with 502 Use --force to continue.**

If uses --force then the issue is skipping and files are made properly.

Can some one help me out how can I resolve this issue in **grunt build**?

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1):

This is a deprecated reference.

You need to update your bower with

```
npm install -g bower
```

or

update the **.bowerrc** file with

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

Also check https://twitter.com/bower/status/918073147789889536

Comment: god bless you :)